# How to add a class attribute to discourse-modal div

Tags: html, css, discourse

I have a particular discourse modal that I want to style a little differently than the others but I can't find a way to add a specific class without it adding it to all the modals.

This is what a modal usual looks like when it is displayed.

```
<div id="discourse-modal" class="ember-view modal hidden in" style="display: block;">
```

I want to be able to add a specific class to each modal so I can use it as a top style to work with For example in the login modal I want to hide the footer but in the edit category modal I want the footer to show. So if I have a class name I can reference at the top level then I can style them differently.

I want to be able to add something like this.

```
<div id="discourse-modal" class="ember-view modal hidden in login-modal" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you just can't add that class?

Comment: Because it's a template and is used for other templates also. Check out modal.js.handlebars Ideal I'd like to add it to the div above this template which is <div id="discourse-modal" class="ember-view modal hidden in"> but I can't find where this is been generated.

Comment: Is it still an issue? What specific modal do you want to customize? We can add the class if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the modal `div`s have specific `id`s you could use that by making reference to them or the footer inside them in `css` like:

```
#login-modal .footer {
    display: none; /*you don't show*/
}

#edit-category-modal .footer {
    /*i'll let you be*/
}
```

But if they don't have `id` or if that isn't good enough, would `js` be a valid solution for you?

In that case maybe you could use the `element.classList.add(`) method. Here's an example:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
divs[0].classList.add("login-modal");
divs[1].classList.add("edit-category-modal");
```

And here's also a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S5ENV/) that ilustrates the point.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks itiel, First off each modal has the same ID. What I'm trying to do is add a unique class to it when items are added to the modal. So if login template is added to the modal then I want to be able to style the modal shell differently. Problem is the shell modal always has the same ID and class names.

Comment: As for JS the problem is the modal in disclosure is show or hidden. In order to use JS I need a way to know if it has been shown and what content is added to it. This would require an ugly setInterval running all the time.

Comment: If you use discourse you will notice it's using ember.js to load templates into a modal. It shows and hides the modal based on the users requests. I'm trying to add a unique class name to each modal shell. So I can style specific modals differently depending on the type of modal it is.